# Panel added dynamically with Bootstrap in wrong way

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I used Collapse panel with Bootstrap and it works fine in static way, but when I try to add it dynamically it didn't work.

#### HTML

```
 <form>
    <div class="form-group" >
      <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea> 
      </div>
     <div style="float: right;"> <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Add Question" id="AddQuestId"></div>       
  </form>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseEleven">What is the currency used for all transactions?</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseEleven" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        All prices for themes, templates and other items, including each seller's or buyer's account balance are in <strong>USD</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$( "#AddQuestId" ).click(function() {
    $("#accordion").append('<div class="panel panel-default">'+
    '<div class="panel-heading">'+
    '<h4 class="panel-title"> '+
    '<a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse14">'+$("#comment").val()+'</a>  </h4>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div id="collapse14" class="panel-collapse collapse in">'+
    '<div class="panel-body">'+
    'Account registration at <strong>PrepBootstrap</strong>'+
    '</div>'+
    '</div>'+
     '</div>'+
    '</h4>'+
     '</div>');
});
```

Comment: Your href for your anchor doesnt match the id of your .panel-collapse. Change the href to #collapse14 and your code works. https://jsfiddle.net/f0uL7v14/

Comment: Try to add another one it didn't work correctly

Comment: @SeanWessell I updated the question please see again

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write whole collapse panel code in javascript. Just use HTML DOM to poulate the dynamic content. one such example is if you want to populate some dynamic content in panel body:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <p id = "description"> All prices for themes, templates and other items, including each seller's or buyer's account balance are in <strong>USD</strong> </p>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
$( "#AddQuestId" ).click(function() {
document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = "Account registration at PrepBootstrap";
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = comment;
    });
```

In the third line I am taking ID for panel title as "id"

Comment: Sorry For being dummy!, I didn't understandwhere is the solution